# Epsilon Transitions in an NFA

Tags: theory

I'm attempting to teach myself the basics of finite automata and have been exploring the differences between  Deterministic Finite Automata and Non Deterministic Finite Automita.

One thing that pops up quite often in the on-line examples, lectures slides and videos of various CS instructors is the epsilon transition. The problem is none of them do very good job of explaining epsilon transitions. They just kind of pop them out of nowhere as this mysterious property that allows a you to jump from one state to another without reading an input character.

O.K. I get that, but how are these arbitrary jumps facilitated semanticly if we were to create this automata? Take the image below for example. Lets say we are in S0, there are two epsilon transitions to s1 and s4. How is it decided which one to go down. If you go to S1 and do not have an a, can you backtrack and try b? I say this because the arrows do not seem to infer this. Or have I conceived this wrong, could the automata  actually be in both states S1 and S2 concurrently?

Also s3 and s6, have epsilon transitions to s7, so why don't we have two accepting states S3 and s4 instead?

Finally the S2, has two paths that react to a, s5 has two paths that react to b. How does that work in practice. How is the path to follow determined?

When answering please try to limit the use of esoteric mathematics, and if you do use operators and symbols explain each one clearly. I'm not a maths wizz.

[image: NFA with Epsilon Transitions]

Comment: I think your main problem is that you treat a NFA as a deterministic one. The epsilon transitions from state s0 indicate that from s0 you can go to {s1, s4}, i.e. to a set that contains both states at the same time.

Comment: So essentially I could pass though NFA generating  an arbitrary quantity of states (forming a set) with all, some or none of them reaching the accepting state?

Comment: Yes. For each state you can have multiple transitions. The ambiguity is due to (1) epsilon-transitions and (2) multiple transitions for a given state and symbol (like for s2 / a). So for each state and symbol you can reach a set of states. Actually, you can always transform a NFA to a DFA where the states in the DFA correspond to set of states in the original NFA. So a NFA is only a convenient way to write down a DFA.

Comment: It can be an interesting exercise to apply the powerset construction (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) to your example and see what you get.

Comment: So would you say it would be more likely an NFA would be converted to a DFA before implementation? or do and can NFAs be implimented directly like DFAs?

Comment: You can run an NFA directly using backtracking. Running the corresponding DFA is like running all the different branches of the NFA in parallel, so no backtracking is needed. As far as I know, it can be convenient to use a NFA for specification but you would convert it to a DFA in order to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a few ideas have already emerged in the comments to the question, I try to collect these ideas in an answer.

I think your main source of confusion is that you try to treat a non-deterministic finite automaton as a deterministic one. The epsilon transitions from state `s0` indicate that from `s0` you can go to `{s1, s4}`, i.e. to a set that contains both states at the same time. The ambiguity "I can go from s0 to s1 and from s0 to s2, which one should I take?" is resolved by taking both at the same time. To be more precise, the epsilon transition tells you that `s0`, `s1`, and `s2` are basically the same state: by being in `s0` you are **already** in `s1` and in `s2` so you can switch to either of them without reading any symbol from the input.

Likewise, you can have an ambiguity if you have two transitions from a state to different states on the same symbol, like for `s2` and `a` in your example. In this case, when in state `s2`, if you read symbol `a` you go to `{s2, s3}`.
What does it mean to be in state `{s2, s3}`? It means from here you can apply both the `s2`-transitions and the `s3`-transitions.

You can always transform a NFA to an equivalent DFA where the states in the DFA correspond to set of states in the original NFA (by applying the [powerset construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction)).

Running an NFA directly would need backtracking while running the corresponding DFA is like running all the different branches of the NFA in parallel (no backtracking is needed): the powerset construction folds all parallel branches together and removes ambiguities.

Comment: Instead of backtracking could you multi thread?

Comment: @Andrew S: This is a completely different question that you should probably ask separately.